# Как подключить JS и CSS в зависимости от котроллера?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Можно как нибудь добавить еще один манифест pipeline ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте там, куда хотите подключить:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'targetstylesheet' if params[:controller] == 'targetcontroller' %>
```

И аналогично для JS